# Space complexity of C# sort on string lists

Tags: c#, algorithm, memory, space-complexity

I'm implementing a program to sort large files that maybe don't fit in memory. All files will be sorted by lines so I'm thinking in use a List to do it.

I already calculated how many lines I can have in memory to split the files in smaller files, but I don't know how many space I need in memory to sort a List of N elements.

The question is, knowing the maximum number of elements (strings of known size) and the available memory, how much space in memory will the List.Sort method will need?

Comment: Side note: for future question skip putting thank you notes and upvote/accept useful answers. I.e. in this one in addition to commenting "thank you" on bubble sort suggestion you could upvoted it.

Comment: I can't, I don't have enough reputation to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<T>.Sort` uses a quicksort algorithm, which is O(log n) space.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Space_complexity

Comment: I'd imagine that you'd need O(n) memory to simply store the string.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on your point of reference.  You might choose to point out that it takes an *additional* O(log n) space, but otherwise this is totally correct. +1

Answer (score 2):

Quick sort is `O(logn)` space complexity, because it stores constant information (beginning and end of the partition) at every recursive level, and there's at most `logn` levels.

The merge itself is in-place, as is the bubble sort fallback, so they're `O(1)` and as such don't count.

Answer (score 2):

Do some research: [List.Sort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx) uses the [QuickSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm by default, which has O(logn) space complexity.

If you are really worried about space complexity and don't mind a slower algorithm you could use [Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) which has O(1) space complexity.

Comment: I'm not that worried about space complexity, I just needed to know how much space I needed. I will take that in consideration though.
Thanks.